# Node.js - leaving domain context

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I have a flow of methods I'm running, and a couple of these operations require a self-contained domain to wrap their operations.

However, if method 1 has a domain, method 3 doesn't, but happens to throw an error. How can I prevent method 1's domain from catching that error?

All of the domain examples I come across don't seem to deal with problems like this.

Contrived example:

```
enter code here

var domain = require('domain');

// should succeed
var firstThing = function (next) {
  var d = domain.create();

  d.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('firstThing: Some error occurred', err);
    next(err);
  });

  d.run(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      // did some stuff
      console.log('did first thing');
      next();
    }, 100);
  });
};


var goodThing = function (next) {
  console.log('doing good thing');
  next();
};

var badThing = function (next) {
  console.log('doing bad thing');
  throw new Error('death');
  next();
};


firstThing(function (err) {
  console.log('err?', err);
  goodThing(function (err) {
    console.log('err again?', err);
    badThing(function (err) {
      console.log('bad news', err);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm essentially looking for a way to "end" the domain in "firstThing" prior to it calling back.

Comment: Could you create a custom Error class that supports domain and create a shared error handler for all your modules?

Comment: I'm probably not understanding you correctly, but, I don't think so as all of these individual modules are pretty small usecases and need the flexibility to be able to run in many situations, i.e. probably not tied to any custom errors or shared handlers

Comment: Hrm. In that case, why even bother worrying where or how your errors are being handled? Let the upstream developer who's using them handle them?

Comment: Because, if I were to call this series of methods with something like: `async.series` It never makes it to the final callback because the `firstThing` passes on to the next in the series, but when the error is caught in `firstThing`s domain error handler, it calls `next` _again_, but that does not exit the flow

Comment: Therefore preventing said developer from handling the error upstream?

Comment: I think the architecture of Node isn't really designed to do things that way - if you're throwing an error, it's going to kill the stack unless it's handled. Short of writing a custom error handler for each domain, there's just no way around it.

Comment: Sure, but, let's say ignore everything beyond `firstThing`. I just don't want `firstThing` to be catching errors after what I would consider to be it's isolated error handling. Regardless of the flow that follows it.

Comment: From the docs, in domain.exit: "Any time execution is going to switch to the context of a different chain of asynchronous calls, it's important to ensure that the current domain is exited." This sounds like what I'm after, but for whatever reason I can't replicate what it suggests.